# How to add hyphen into a string if it exceed certain length?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a zipcode column. Some of the zip codes are five digits, some are nine digits. I need to insert a hyphen between the fifth and sixth characters if the field is nine characters.

55555 remains 55555

999999999 becomes 99999-9999

I could possibly add them when echoing with PHP, but it would be more efficient if I could just add the hyphen to the data in the zipcode column in the database.

Comment: `CONCAT(SUBSTR(zip, 1, 5), '-', SUBSTR(zip, 6))`...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to update the value, you could use this update query:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  zip = CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTR(zip, 1, 5), SUBSTR(zip, 6))
WHERE
  LENGTH(zip)=9
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19c7c/1).

Comment: Yes! Exactly. I couldn't quite wrap my head around the logic, seeing it, concat makes perfect sense and I am pleased to learn of concat_ws. Thank you.